# Bootstrap button not working on smartphone

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button, touch, smartphone

I'm building a website that will allow the user to review and create new orders. I'm using Bootstrap 3 buttons to move between pages.
Now I've encountered a problem:
On my desktop and tablet (android 4.1) all goes well but on smartphones (used several brands) nothing happens when I click or tap these buttons. The same goes for a  list.

I've tried lots of code I could find all over the web but none seem to be willing to work.

I have no idea what is going wrong. My Chrome debug console says all is OK, no errors.

Some examples I tried:

```
<button id="NewPr" class="btn btn-default">Nieuwe offerte aanvragen</button>
<button id="act1" class="btn btn-default">Offerte-aanvragen ouder dan 3 maanden</button>&nbsp;
<button id="act2" class="btn btn-default">Geannuleerde offerte-aanvragen</button>&nbsp;
<button id="act2" class="btn btn-default">Gefactureerde projecten</button>
           </div>

<script>    
function init(){
var Act1Touch = document.getElementById("Act1");
Act1Touch.addEventListener("touchstart", Act1Handler, false);

var NewPrTouch = document.getElementById("NewPr");
NewPrTouch.addEventListener("touchstart", NewPrHandler, false);

}

function NewPrHandler(){
alert ("NewPR OK");
}

function Act1Handler(){
alert ("Act1 OK");
}

/* alternatives I tried */
/* Alt 1 */
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#NewPr").on('touchend mousedown click tap vclick', function(e){
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
alert ("new");
    AddProject();
    });

$("#act1").on('touchend mousedown click tap vclick', function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
alert ("act1");
    DisplayStuff(1);
    });
});

/* Alt 2*/
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#NewPr').click( function(){
alert ("new");
        AddProject();
        });

$('#act1').click( function(){
alert("act1");
        DisplayStuff(1);
        });

$('#act2').click( function(){
alert("act2");
        DisplayStuff(2);
        });

$('#act3').click( function(){
alert("act3");
        DisplayStuff(3);
        });

});*/
```

Comment: Can you remote debug on smarth phone? Also what is os uour smartphone? https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/&ved=0ahUKEwiltN28htnWAhWhE5oKHYpDBaYQFggxMAI&usg=AOvVaw09tqMxMrG3UG89T3tOPxJu

Comment: You're trying to get an element with an ID of 'Act1' but the button ID is actually 'act1'. That might be an issue, not sure.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that little type error. But even with the correct ID it still doesn't work.
I've tested it on a Samsung and a One+, both with Android. As said on my tablet (medion) with Android too, everything works fine.
My bootstrap selection lists also don't fire when viewed on these smartphones but do work on dektop and tablet.

Could it be something in the Bootstrap CSS or js code that isn't working when the site is displayed on a smartphone screen?

Comment: I've tested it on an iPhone 6 too and the same result: nothing works. Only when I place the button in a form will it work but my page has no use for a form. The buttons are needed as action buttons.

Comment: You have two buttons with `id="act2"` ... that never goes well. Can you fix up your code example with unique and correctly cased names?

Comment: Correct, but that was due to copy past in this post. In the original code I only have one button with that ID.
While researching a bit more I discovered what the error was:
In my code I have a div with classes row and col-lg-10. This works perfectly on every platform except smartphones.
When I moved the row class to a separate div all works fine.
I know this is not the way Bootstrap was supposed to work (row and col dimensions in the same div but for some reason it does work on PC and tablet. I've changed the code and all works fine now.